# lmfit for Gaussian fitting indexerror: index 80 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 80

Tags: python

I am trying to use lmfit to get the variables , height, center, fwhm. I have an array with the shape 126, 80. But when I run the code it tells me IndexError: index 80 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 80. I know this is probably due to it trying to run bigger than the size 80, but I can't figure out where I am wrong. It runs the fitting all the way up to 80 then outputs the error.

This is the array:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sBCuo4ns0klXItlVNkX-ulaDddbYH5Y0/view?usp=sharing[hdata][1]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sBCuo4ns0klXItlVNkX-ulaDddbYH5Y0/view?usp=sharing%5Bhdata%5D%5B1%5D)

Luminescence wavelength array: Which is basically the shape 126 in the hdata: [lum_wavelength](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ew6PDV_GaqzHNHuC2c5uKNR5zB5PgWp/view?usp=sharing)

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, ExponentialModel, ConstantModel

def Gauss4Fit(x, y, if_plt):  
  for i in range (len(hdata)):
    y = np.array(hdata[:,i])
    x = luminescence_wavelength
    mod = GaussianModel()
    pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)
    result = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
    print(result.fit_report())
    result.plot_fit()
    plt.show()

  gauss1  = GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
  pars.update( gauss1.make_params())
  pars['g1_center']

  pars['g1_height']
  pars['g1_fwhm']
  mod2 = gauss1
  init = mod2.eval(pars, x=x)
  out = mod2.fit(y, pars, x=x, method = 'slsqp') #method = 'slsqp' nelder

  return out.values
  #print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.1))
  if if_plt:
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot(x, init, 'k--')
    plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-')
    plt.show()



dataset = hdata[:,:]/500
result_arr = np.zeros((hdata.shape[0],hdata.shape[1],3))

for x in range(hdata.shape[0]):
  print(x)
  for y in range(hdata.shape[1]):
    temp = Gauss4Fit(luminescence_wavelength, hdata[x,y], x == 0)
    result_arr[x,y,0] =  temp['g1_height']
    result_arr[x,y,1] =  temp['g1_center']
    result_arr[x,y,2] =  temp['g1_fwhm']
```

Comment: I get this error: `NameError: name 'luminescence_wavelength' is not defined`. What is that variable set to?

Comment: @NickODell I added the array file, it is basically the 126 in the hdata file so shape[0].

Comment: I think I found the error - I think `range (len(hdata))` is probably supposed to be `range(hdata.shape[1])`. Otherwise, it loops from 0 to 125 instead of 0 to 79. Beyond that, I can't tell what the code is intended to do.